# Android varying number of textviews to display

Tags: java, android

For exmaple I have int variable "number" that is passed throughout the program

and if the number = 7 I want to create 7 identical textviews and create 7 IDs for each of them

if the number = 5 I want to create 5 textviews etc.

My guess is that I should not create any `textviews in my xml file` and rather `create views in my java code`. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Obviously if your view is dynamic you should do it programmatically.

Comment: If you know upfront what types of components you want, you can create them, get their references in an array and then only use 7 or 5 depending on what number is entered. But the best way seems to be programmatically creating the views in code like the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a XML holding the EditText and a ListView in another xml, then in the Adapter of that ListView you can inflate and instanciate the EditText XML items.

This way you stay much cleaner and it might be less work if you change style etc. You do not need to take care of a scrollview yourself for more items.

Also you can have items and ListView adapting to screendensity, screensize, orientation etc. without going through a hell of code - if this is a requirement.

If the last item in the list needs to be a button, you could inflate and instanciate such an item layout too in the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If your layout is unknown at compile time (for example, the number of `View`s is not known), then your only choice is to do it programatically.